# Wrong output of preg_split

Tags: php, regex

I have this input

```
foo     par1, par2
foo1    par3, par4:6
foo2    par7:00ff00
```

I need to divide every line - by newlines, tabs and commas and colons. Every each in different part of code. I do it like this

```
$output = preg_split("/\n|\r /", $input_string,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // new lines
$output2 = preg_split( "/\t|\v /", $output[$i] ); // tabs in loop, thats why $i
$output3 = preg_split( "/[:,]+/", $different_output2); // Last divide string contains no foo parts of string
```

Desired output:

```
 array(2){
    [0]=>
    string(4) "par1"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "par2"
}
```

Instead, the output is like this

```
 array(2){
    [0]=>
    string(4) "par1"
    [1]=>
  " string(4) "par2    
}
```

The quotation marks in front are the problem. That makes a mess when I work later with the array.

Comment: can you give an example of the desired output ?

Comment: It's there. I know for first time you see no difference. I'll edit it a lil then

Comment: Can you please provide the desired result ? I cannot yet understand what you  need as output of this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using trim() function combined with preg_split. There are unexpected blank space to deal with. So the best option is.

```
$output3 = preg_split( "/[:,]+/", trim($different_output2));
```